# Can scheduled web request be authorized by MVC controllers?

Tags: model-view-controller, web, request, quartz.net

My web app has to do some calculations in the background. I've investigated multiple solutions and I would like to go for business logic instead of a SQL job that triggers all the calculations. After a few days of research I'm still not convinced what is the best solution for my case.

A lot of articles mention Quartz.NET, a separate windows service (but I think that's not an option on most shared web host services), a windows task, etc...

To keep the calculations in the business logic I would extend my web application with a dedicated 'task' controller that fires the calculations automatically and then returns a result of its actions.

Q1: Calling the controller with a Quartz.NET timed web request will not be that hard, **but how can I secure it?** If I add the [Authorize] attribute to my 'task' controller it will block the request. (note that I use forms authentication on my internet web application) I don't want users on the internet to be able to launch my 'task' controller.

Q2: Also if what I'm thinking is correct that shared web host services don't support the installation of separate windows services or remote desktop connections, I'll have 2 options:

- hope there is support for windows tasks at the shared web host service (**but can this be called with authorization credentials?**)
- start the Quartz.NET from my application_start (which is certainly not an ideal solution...)

Thanks in advance

Kr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, I wouldn't call ASP.NET MVC controller from scheduled job. I'd just delegate to business components / services (whatever the name is) and make sure there that we run correct things with context's permissions. This could mean that I fire the job with information about for whom the calculation is done and pass that information to service component (calculate daily average for user X). I don't see a real benefit from masquerading the call with ASP.NET MVC stack.

So Q1: Secure in code level, not using ASP.NET MVC stack

You can always run without windows service, then you just take the risk of app pool shutting down when not in use. One way to get by this is to have a external ping program that makes sure that there are calls made, not ideal as you pointed out. Having jobs and triggers in database protects from losing information but not from misfires.

Q2: most likely running Quartz.NET is far easier than trying to access Windows Scheduled Tasks.

Some shared providers have very strict settings for code to run. It might be that Quartz.NET won't run at all if too tightly sandboxed.